# SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight fails to update the content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I have a window with a `Grid`. The `SizeToContent` property of `Window` is set to `WidthAndHeight`. The window doesn't refresh the behaviour of the content(`TextTrimming` not carried out).

When the`SizeToContent = Manual` the `TextTrimming` is functioning but When the`SizeToContent = Manual` the `TextTrimming` is not done. But when i actually resizes my window the `SizeToContent` property automatically changes to `Manual`(True according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.sizetocontent?view=netframework-4.7.2).).

```
<Window x:Class="TextTrimmingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextTrimmingTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
>
<Grid Margin="0 30 0 0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"  MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  MinWidth="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  MinWidth="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  MinWidth="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Text1111111"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Text 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                   Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Cutttttttttttttttt" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                   Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Materialllllllllllllllllllll" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Grid.Column="3"
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                   Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Upon the window loaded the content should be arranged in such way that when a `SizeToContent` property is set to `Manual`

Comment: If you run my example you could see that MinWidth of my TextBlocks are ignored. The content is not updated( I don't know the correct word for that.). When you resize the window the textblock shows the trimming behaviour. I hope my problem is clear for you.

Comment: Anybody has the same problem??